# How to use Redux-Saga inside a class

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, generator, yield, redux-saga

I have an idea to separate `sagas` according to their responsibility. I have created a base class for saga handlers as follows.

```
 export class BaseSagaHandler {

  static isGenerator(fn) {
    return fn.endsWith('Gen');
  }

  forkAllSagaFunctions() {
    const sagaFuncs = [];
    const functions = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this.constructor.prototype);
    functions.forEach(func => {
      if (BaseSagaHandler.isGenerator(String(func))) {
        sagaFuncs.push(fork([this, this[func]]));
      }
    });
    return sagaFuncs;
  }
}
```

As you can see from the code above, I stick to convention that we need to use all methods that end with `Gen` as `Sagas`. 
Here is an example of a child class

```
export class LocaleSaga extends BaseSagaHandler {
  private localeService: ILocaleService;

  constructor(localeService: ILocaleService) {
    super();
    this.localeService = localeService;
  }

  public* setCurrentLocale(locale) {
    yield call([this, this.localeService.setCurrentLocale], locale);
    yield put(WITH_PAYLOAD(SUCCESS(ACTION_TYPES.SET_LOCALE), locale));
  }

  public* setLocaleSagaGen() {
    yield takeLatest(REQUEST(ACTION_TYPES.SET_LOCALE), this.setCurrentLocale);
  }
}
```

This class is instantiated in the following manner.

```
const diContainer = rootDiContainer;
const localeSagas = new LocaleSaga(diContainer.get<ILocaleService>(LOCALE_SERVICE_TYPE)).forkAllSagaFunctions();
export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([
    localeSagas
  ]);
}
```

So basically we listen for a specific action and than call a function. However I have a problem on this line.

```
yield takeLatest(REQUEST(ACTION_TYPES.SET_LOCALE), this.setCurrentLocale);
```

As far as I am passing the class method, when it reaches the `setCurrentLocale` function `this` is `null`. The `take*` methods don't support passing context as I could see from source code and documentation, but `fork,call` functions allow passwing `context` together with function.

Is there any way I can pass class method reference with the context of the class?

P.S. Please let me know whether my idea has any pitfalls or doesn't make any sense.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to **Andrey Moiseev's** answer, I have decided to combine two methods into a single one with an anonymous generator function as follows.

```
public* setLocaleSagaGen() {
    const context = this;
    yield takeEvery(REQUEST(ACTION_TYPES.SET_LOCALE), function* (locale) {
      const result = yield call([context.localeService, context.localeService.setCurrentLocale], locale);
      yield put(WITH_PAYLOAD(SUCCESS(ACTION_TYPES.SET_LOCALE), result));
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Javascript, `this` [depends on where you're calling the function from](https://medium.com/@anjalisharma0626/what-is-call-site-of-a-function-8e5d9881c49e).

The problem is that the saga that you pass to `takeLatest()` is being called *later* from inside of redux-saga internals. Unless redux-saga accepts `context`, saves it, and later manually supplies it as `this` (unfortunately it doesn't), it does not work.

I see two possible options.

**Using standard `takeLatest()`**

- Save `this` as `context` in the function scope.
- Pass an inline saga to `takeLatest()`. This saga is a closure that has access to `context`.

The code:

```
public* setLocaleSagaGen() {
  const context = this
  yield takeLatest(REQUEST(ACTION_TYPES.SET_LOCALE), function*() {
    yield call([context, context.setCurrentLocale])
  })
}
```

**Using a custom `takeLatest()`**

In redux-saga docs there is an [example implementation of `takeLatest()`](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#takelatestpattern-saga-args). I modified it to accept and pass on context:

```
const takeLatestWithContext = (patternOrChannel, [context, saga], ...args) => fork(function*() {
  let lastTask
  while (true) {
    const action = yield take(patternOrChannel)
    if (lastTask) {
      yield cancel(lastTask) // cancel is no-op if the task has already terminated
    }
    lastTask = yield fork([context, saga], ...args.concat(action))
  }
})
```

So it can be used like:

```
  public* setLocaleSagaGen() {
    const context = this
    yield takeLatest(REQUEST(ACTION_TYPES.SET_LOCALE), [this.context, this.setCurrentLocale]);
  }
```

In this case, saving `this` is not necessary, because `takeLatest()` arguments are evaluated immediately.

Comment: Thank you for the answer I have combined two methods in order to be able to access context inside the generator function, I have updated my question. Do you think my idea to group sagas in that way makes any sense?

Comment: @CROSP Yes, I think it's ok.